# Selenium python cannot find name or email address element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to automatically login the website using selenium with python. However, I got error as below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KienThong\Automation\Learning\GmailDemo.py", line 15, in <module>
    ID = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
  File "C:\Python385\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.englishforum.com/study/login/")
driver.maximize_window()
try:
    ID = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "_xfUid-1-1643985254"))
    )
    ID.send_keys("dkthong2010@gmail.com")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Which element is that in the UI?

Comment: It's the Email input bar, I am trying to fill in the Email input bar

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are having an error is that the ID that you are using is dynamic and changes everytime the page is loaded. Therefore we need to use a static identifier which we can with `name="login"`

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.englishforum.com/study/login/")
driver.maximize_window()
try:
    ID = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "login"))
    )
    ID.send_keys("dkthong2010@gmail.com")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But how can you tell the dynamic ID from the static ID?

Comment: @KThong when you refresh the page the ID would change (dynamic) versus the name (which we used) would be static (doesn't change on refresh)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to tell the driver to wait till the element is present your can simply its xpath as it will executed only after page loads
so use:

```
   ID = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/dl[1]/dd/input")
   ID.send_keys("dkthong2010@gmail.com")
```

using xpath to locating the element is very easy and easy to locate.
just
1.inspect the element
2.right click on the element
3. copy full xpath

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the ***Your name or email address*** field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.englishforum.com/study/login/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='dismiss-notice'] > span.button-text"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='login']"))).send_keys("dkthong2010@gmail.com")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.englishforum.com/study/login/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'dismiss-notice')]/span[@class='button-text']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='login']"))).send_keys("dkthong2010@gmail.com")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: englishforum]